# request.body.name not working in expressjs app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes, ejs

i am using route to create a author object and passing the author's name as paramter and testing the value is passed by res.send(req.body.name) in post route. but i dont see any output and i get the following error. undefined. the code is as shown below

```
router.post('/',async(req,res)=>{
res.send(req.body.name)
console.log(req.body.name)
})
```

please help is there a problem with request its working when i pass static values `res.send('karunkar')`.
please help

Comment: i am assuming you are using express, have you added body-parser middle-ware to your application?

Comment: Please post full code and also post on how you are passing the name parameter

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are not parsing incoming json

```
import * as express from "express";
const app = express();
// applying middlewares in express
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Body-parser is deprecated so use express.json and urlencoded.